# How to add input types dynamically when dropdown menu clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I want to do: When the `dropdown item` is `clicked` I want to add a new `div` with an `input` inside of it and name it based on the clicked item. I'm a complete newbie to javascript. Can someone give me ideas on how to do this?

Here's a sample picture. Example when I click an `item` in `dropdown menu` it will add another `div` with `input` type inside of it. Like the Major Exam. 
[image]

Here's my code.

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"> 
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Criteria for grading</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body edit-content">
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action ="edit2.php?newsid=<?=$row['news_id']?>">
                    <div class="dropdown">

                        <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Add Criteria <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Assignment</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Attendance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Laboratory</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Activity</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Recitation</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div class="well">
                        <label for="majore">Major Exam</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control majore"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-percent"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="well">
                        <label for="majore">Quizzes</label>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it will add another div with input type inside of it"? Also, don't you need to differentiate between the Major Exam and Quizzes divs and inputs?

Comment: @tim-diztinct it will add another input like the major exam and the quizzes. Exactly like that sir. With the well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is tagged jQuery, so I will use it.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li").on("click", function(){
    var name = $(this).find("a").text();
    var newDiv = $(".well").first().clone();
    $(newDiv).find("label").text(name);
    newDiv.insertAfter(".well").last();
});
```

I would think you'd want to add the name of the dropdown li clicked to the new form, but you didn't include that in your question.

Comment: It worked, it adds a div but it's adding two divs. And the name of it it's still major and quizzes.

Comment: How can i do it with a different name?

Comment: Can you edit your question to ask how to do that? I also asked you in the comment of your question.

Comment: Try now. It will add the clicked link's text to the label of the cloned form.

Comment: can i used and insert the data in database the value of clone input type?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand a problem. I copy/pasted this code form manual for bootstrap...

```css
form {
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li>
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
          <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
          <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Check me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>


    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```